# angular js cannot resolve state from state

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im trying to create a substate memstate in a state called single_post , in order to reach this state from the single_post controller with

```
$state.go(single_post({id:somename});
```

but im getting an error every time telling me the following
"Error: Could not resolve 'single_post.memstate({id :somename})' from state 'single_post'"

here is the app.js code

```
    var app = angular.module('app',['ui.router','ui.router.stateHelper','ngCookies']);
app.config(function($stateProvider){
index = {
    name : 'index',
    url : "",
    views : {
        'slider' :{
            templateUrl : 'template/slider.html',
            controller : 'slider_ctrl'
        },
        'content' : {
            templateUrl : 'template/posts-area.html',
            controller  : 'posts_ctrl'
        }
    }
};
single_post = {
    name : 'single_post',
    url  : '/t/{id:int}',
    views : {
        'content' : {
            templateUrl : 'template/single-post.html',
            controller  : 'single_post_ctrl'
        },
        'mem_handle' :{
            templateUrl :'template/lginform.html',
            controller : 'login_con'
        }
    }
};
loginstate = {
    name : 'single_post.loginstate',
    url : '/login',
    views : {
        'mem_handle' :{
            templateUrl :'template/lginform.html',
            controller : 'login_con'
        }

    }


};
regstate = {
    name : 'single_post.regstate',
    url  : '/register',
    views :{
        'mem_handle' :{
            templateUrl : 'template/regform.html',
            controller : 'reg_con'
        }
    }
};
memstate = {
    name : 'single_post.memstate',
    url : '/m/{id:string}/',
    views : {
        'content' : {
            template : 'member.html',
            controller : 'mem_controller'
        }
    }
}
$stateProvider.state('index',index);
$stateProvider.state('single_post',single_post);
$stateProvider.state('single_post.regstate',regstate);
$stateProvider.state('single_post.loginstate',loginstate);
$stateProvider.state('single_post.memstate',memstate);

});
```

Comment: You missed one bracket in `$state.go(single_post({id:somename}));` Once check by correcting that.

Comment: I tried it putting that bracket but nothing happend , I found the solution of the problem , thank you alot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all ,
the problem was in passing parameters to a state using $state ..
I found out that the correct way is

```
$state.go('single_post.memstate',{id:$cookies.get('an')});
```

by passing the parameters as object to the function $state.go();